# Internet transfer taking ages for elastic beanstalk environment, with traceroute showing strange output

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an EBS environment set up in AWS us-east-1, and I'm calling it from Australia via http. There is a DNS set up in front of it on route 53, and I'm calling it via that. I'm aware that having the infra in us-east-1 should add some latency impact in terms of the internet speed.

However, the latency increase seems to be way more than normal. My analysis has shown that it takes 200ms for the endpoint to return a response, the response being 6000 characters of text, but then 900ms end-to-end for the data to hit my computer. That means the data transfer time over the internet is taking 700ms.

This latency is much less (about 100ms for data transfer) if i return for example just 20 characters. I've tried other endpoints in us-east-1 and they transfer the data a lot faster, so my internet connection is unlikely to be the issue. I tried doing a traceroute and here was the output. I'm not skilled at reading traceroute so im not sure if this is misconfigured:

```
1  mymodem (192.168.0.1)  5.515 ms  4.140 ms  4.416 ms
 2  gateway.vb09.melbourne.asp.telstra.net (58.162.26.201)  13.920 ms  18.528 ms  14.207 ms
 3  ae10.lon-ice301.melbourne.telstra.net (203.50.61.129)  15.245 ms
    ae10.win-ice301.melbourne.telstra.net (203.50.61.145)  14.800 ms  13.342 ms
 4  bundle-ether25.exi-core30.melbourne.telstra.net (203.50.61.128)  15.015 ms  15.545 ms
    bundle-ether25.win-core10.melbourne.telstra.net (203.50.61.144)  15.603 ms
 5  bundle-ether2.cla-core30.melbourne.telstra.net (203.50.13.124)  15.580 ms  15.727 ms  15.234 ms
 6  bundle-ether19.chw-core10.sydney.telstra.net (203.50.13.144)  26.375 ms
    bundle-ether3.hay-core30.sydney.telstra.net (203.50.13.132)  26.279 ms  27.283 ms
 7  bundle-ether1.oxf-gw11.sydney.telstra.net (203.50.6.93)  25.961 ms
    bundle-ether19.ken-core10.sydney.telstra.net (203.50.13.146)  26.221 ms  26.505 ms
 8  203.50.13.98 (203.50.13.98)  27.733 ms
    bundle-ether1.pad-gw11.sydney.telstra.net (203.50.6.61)  26.582 ms
    203.50.13.98 (203.50.13.98)  26.650 ms
 9  203.50.13.98 (203.50.13.98)  180.096 ms
    203.50.13.90 (203.50.13.90)  26.194 ms  27.483 ms
10  203.50.13.90 (203.50.13.90)  165.233 ms  162.661 ms  163.185 ms
11  i-73.paix-core02.telstraglobal.net (202.84.247.45)  185.490 ms  181.710 ms  179.565 ms
12  i-92.paix02.telstraglobal.net (202.84.247.41)  180.893 ms
    i-92.eqnx03.telstraglobal.net (202.84.247.17)  160.601 ms  161.498 ms
13  gtt-peer.paix02.pr.telstraglobal.net (134.159.61.98)  327.221 ms  183.915 ms
    64.86.160.0 (64.86.160.0)  163.227 ms
14  ae11.cr7-dal3.ip4.gtt.net (213.200.115.26)  240.476 ms
    ae12.cr7-dal3.ip4.gtt.net (213.200.120.106)  242.111 ms
    64.86.160.5 (64.86.160.5)  220.202 ms
15  ip4.gtt.net (209.120.154.162)  213.780 ms  293.630 ms  308.845 ms
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
31  * * *
32  * * *
33  * * *
34  * * *
35  * * *
36  * * *
37  * * *
38  * * *
39  * * *
40  * * *
41  * * *
42  * * *
43  * * *
44  * * *
45  * * *
46  * * *
47  * * *
48  * * *
49  * * *
50  * * *
51  * * *
52  * * *
53  * * *
54  * * *
55  * * *
56  * * *
57  * * *
58  * * *
59  * * *
60  * * *
61  * * *
62  * * *
63  * * *
64  * * *
```

I also tried pinging the endpoint and got the following

```
.Request timeout for icmp_seq 240
```

If anyone could let me know if this is misconfigured or point me to what I should test/analyse to improve the data transfer latency that would be so useful.

Comment: LOL, an incredible number of hops in without leaving the Telstra domain.   This is not a programming question though, and even if it were on topic, it would probably not help future visitors. Network topologies change over time.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed disturbingly many hops within Telstra's network!  But Internet was designed to be resilient, rather than efficient.

AWS offers more optimal routing through its own private network with [Global Accelerator](https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/), if your use case calls for a global service out of a single AWS region.  Otherwise it may be cheaper to run replication across several AWS regions close to your users, and there are quite a few possible architectures with different tradeoffs between latency and cost, which will have to be considered in the context of your specific application.

Finally, to let the ping through to your instance, you will need to enable inbound rule for `Custom ICMP - IPv4` traffic in your security group.